# Просто перестала загружаться сцена в Unity, как исправить?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Сижу пишу код для своей игры, как обычно, добавляю что-нибудь, проверяю, работает ли это или нужно внести правки. Дописал новый метод, открыл Unity, нажал на кнопку Play после этого она осталась в состоянии нажатия, Unity полностью зависла, удалось закрыть только через *Диспетчер задач*. Перезагрузил комп, почистил кеш, пересоздал проект, все равно тоже самое, но во втором проекте все работает, значит проблема не в Unity. Попробовал скомпилировать виснущий проект и посмотреть, запуститься ли он на телефоне, но ничего не получилось. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Что делать?

```
private void OnApplicationPause(bool _pause)
{        
if (!_pause)
{
    Load();          
}
else
{    
    Save();
}
}
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LittleLuckPerSecond());
    StartCoroutine(HelperPerSecond());

    StartCoroutine(MinusClickPerSecond());

}
```

Comment: Как вы пишите загрузку.  Покажите эту строку

Comment: Вот, пожалуйста

Comment: Что в корутинах? И, к слову, они могут выполняться не в том порядке. Стартуют - да - в таком порядке, но в зависимости от кода в корутинах - они могут (что скорее всего есть) выполняться параллельно

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я разобрался! И да, проблема была в корутинах, именно в последней, все заработало после того, как я ее переписал.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, корутины не могут выполняться параллельно ни при каких обстоятельствах

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, я в том плане, что они могут выполняться вместе. И код, который в `Start` - не означает, что сначала выполнится корутина `LittleLuckPerSecond`и только потом начнется выполнение `HelperPerSecond`. Они только запустятся в такой последовательности, а выполняться могут параллельно не в плане "параллельных потоков", а в плане выполнения всех трех корутин в одном кадре. Просто слово "параллельно" мне показалось лучше, чем "хаотично" (н-р, 1 кор. ждет несколько кадров, вторая и третья выполняются; потом продолжают работу все три; затем вторая завершает работы, но продолжают п1 и 3)

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, все же фраза "могут выполняться параллельно" сбивает с толку, поэтому и написал :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в корутинах, последняя корутина просто не могла работать из-за ошибки в коде